# International US phone number mask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

I am using react-native-material-textfield and need a solution to format US number in realtime while user is typing: e.g from '0000000000' to '+1 (000) 000-0000'.

```
  <TextField
      type={'custom'}
      keyboardType='numeric'
      returnKeyType='done'
      underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      value={this.state.maskedPhone}
      onChangeText={text => {
      this.setState({
            maskedPhone: text,
            phone: text.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(1)
      
         });
      }
      formatText={this.formatText}
  />
```

Somehow I could mask text, but without international code (+1 ) like so

```
formatText = text => {
   let x = text.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
   let maskedText = !x[2]
     ? x[1]
     : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');

   return maskedText;
 };
```

As it is being called in realTime just adding '+1 ' at the start of the string doesn't solve the problem as in the end it changes the input value to +1 (111) 111-1111. 
Thank You!

Comment: Not clear on what is the problem. Could you please explain clearer like input and expected output.

Comment: I need to input phone number '7777777777' and get it in this way '+1 (777) 777-7777'

Comment: Ok thanks. Just adding '+1 ' doesn't solve the problem. - What do you mean ? It shows an error or it doesnt gets added ?

Comment: I am listening to the input event and calling this function while typing to have it formatted during typing. Adding '+1 ' in the beginning changes my input value and in the end I get phone number +1 (111) 111-1111 in every case. Thank you.

Comment: When asked for clarification it's best to edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should stand alone and readers should not be expected to read all comments to figure out what you want to do. Moreover, comments may be deleted, possibly leaving your replies meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = '1234567890';
const re = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/;
const output = input.replace(re, (_, a, b, c) => `+1 (${a}) ${b}-${c}`);
console.log(output); // +1 (123) 456-7890
```

Comment: this works only when typed 10 digits, before that number doesn't get formatted and if user continues typing after that the number should be still 10 not become smth like this `+1 (123) 456-+1 (123) 456-7899 `

Comment: If you want a solution that works live while the user is typing in the number, update your question with a live code snippet implementing what you've tried so far (including textbox).  It's not clear at all from your question that you wanted a realtime solution.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I have updated my question to make it more clear.